# items of div, messes up the CSS layout

Tags: css, layout

why the layout is messed up?
why the p element is doing this?
why the first div is a little bit closer to the bottom of the page

```css
#pricing div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 2px black;
}
```

```html
<section id="pricing">
  <div id="plan-1m">
    <!--try without p -->
    <p>why this p messes up the layout?</p>
  </div>
  <div id="plan-3m">
  </div>
  <div id="plan-12m">
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `vertical-align: top;` to your div element.

The default value is `vertical-align: baseline;`, and for what I understand from [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align), it tries to align the bottom of your p with the bottom of other divs (because they don't have any content)